# Compare 2 pyspark dataframe columns and change values of another column based on it

Tags: pyspark

I have a problem where I have generated a dataframe from a graph algorithm that I have written. The thing is that I want to keep the value of the underlying component to be the same essentially after every run of the graph code.

This is a sample dataframe generated:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 'A1'), 
        (1, 'A2'),
        (1, 'A3'),
        (2, 'B1'),
        (2, 'B2'),
        (3, 'B3'),
        (4, 'C1'),
        (4, 'C2'),
        (4, 'C3'),
        (4, 'C4'),
        (5, 'D1'),
    ],
    ['old_comp_id', 'db_id'] 
)
```

After another run the values change completely, so the new run has values like these,

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (2, 'A1'), 
        (2, 'A2'),
        (2, 'A3'),
        (3, 'B1'),
        (3, 'B2'),
        (3, 'B3'),
        (1, 'C1'),
        (1, 'C2'),
        (1, 'C3'),
        (1, 'C4'),
        (4, 'D1'),
    ],
    ['new_comp_id', 'db_id'] 
)
```

So the thing I need to do is to compare the values between the above two dataframes and change the values of the component id based on the database id associated.

1. if the database_id are the same then update the component id to be from the 1st dataframe
2. if they are different then assign a completely new comp_id (new_comp_id = max(old_comp_id)+1)

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
old_ids = df.groupBy("old_comp_id").agg(F.collect_set(F.col("db_id")).alias("old_db_id"))
new_ids = df2.groupBy("new_comp_id").agg(F.collect_set(F.col("db_id")).alias("new_db_id"))

joined = new_ids.join(old_ids,old_ids.old_comp_id == new_ids.new_comp_id,"outer")

joined.withColumn("update_comp", F.when( F.col("new_db_id") == F.col("old_db_id"), F.col('old_comp_id')).otherwise(F.max(F.col("old_comp_id")+1))).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use aggregated functions in non-aggregated columns, you should use Windowing Functions.

First, you outer-join the DFs with the db_id:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col, max
joinedDF = df.join(df2, df["db_id"] == df2["new_db_id"], "outer")
```

Then, start to building the Window (which where you group by db_id, and order by old_comp_id, in order to have in first rows the old_comp_id with highest value.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc
windowSpec = Window\
.partitionBy("db_id")\
.orderBy(desc("old_comp_id"))\
.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
```

Then, you build the max column using the windowSpec

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max
maxCompId = max(col("old_comp_id")).over(windowSpec)
```

Then, you apply it on the select

```
joinedDF.select(col("db_id"), when(col("new_db_id").isNotNull(), col("old_comp_id")).otherwise(maxCompId+1).alias("updated_comp")).show()
```

For more information, please refer to the documentation (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window)

Hope this helps